# What is a safe way to exit a user's shell?

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation, sudo

If I change to a potentially compromised user in Unix, for example by using `su` or `sudo -i`, then exit with `exit`, the compromised user could alias `exit` to something which drops me into a fake shell which has a keylogger. For example, I might:

1. `su` to compromised user
2. `exit` back to safe user, but it doesn't actually exit
3. Use `sudo` to do something as root, but since I'm still in the compromised shell the compromised user could have set up a keylogger
4. Compromised user has root.

How can I safely leave a shell of a compromised user?

Comment: Why would you want to change to a compromised account in the first place?

Comment: `^d` works for me, but they could always change the user's default shell to a custom one that handles it differently. Just kill it from another shell instead.

Comment: *"If I change to a potentially compromised user in Unix"*: then you are running potentially malicious code and anything can happen. Simply don't do that.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change to that user, but assuming you somehow did, I would use kill -9 from a higher privilege user. It is not just the exit command that could be malicious.

Comment: @Arminius I mainly meant if there's a chance of it being compromised; say maybe somebody who isn't super trustworthy has access to the account. User accounts are supposed to be secure from each other so I would imagine that nothing bad can happen to your account by simply switching to another one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do not drop to a lesser user using su or sudo from a shell.**

While what you propose is a valid risk, there is another, much bigger risk when dropping to a lesser user and then exiting, called the TTY pushback attack, using the TIOCSTI IOCTL. This allows arbitrary data to be sent to the calling shell from the child.

From http://www.halfdog.net/Security/2012/TtyPushbackPrivilegeEscalation/:

> When su -s /bin/bash [user] is called from interactive shell, the input queue data pushed back as the target user will be executed by the interactive shell calling su.